# Overlaying PDF map onto satellite image using Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, georeferencing, pdf

I have a PDF map of property limits (black lines on white background).

I'd like to overlay it onto a satellite image (google maps is fine, but really any that is precise enough) to show errors in the property limits. The pdf is 1:1000 scale and contains little useful info, not much georeferencing info as far as I can tell: "Foglio 8 A11:B" and "1 particella 166" and "N=32400 E=-26200". Yes, it's in Italy.

So I'd probably have to do it manually which is fine since it's a one-off.

I'm very ignorant on the kind of tools I can use.

Is there a way to import it into Google Maps?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make map tiles
use QGIS Desktop to build folder of Tiles and then give the https://someurl/somefolder/z/x/y.jpg url to your map

Comment: OK, I've never used Qgis so I'm already struggling to simply display at satellite map... Can't find OpenLayers...

Comment: OK, thanks, that put me on the right track. I used QGis georeferencer and clicked on common points between the sat image and the pdf, it worked.